# Getting two errors while compiling C code on a Linux virtual Machine

Tags: c, linux

I'm new to Linux and C and when trying to run a basic "Hello World" script, i kept getting the same two errors. I have confirmed that everything in the program is correct. 
[errors gotten when trying to compile code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbOrJ.jpg)

Comment: "I have confirmed that everything in the program is correct." How?

Comment: Please, do not link images of output text. Copy and paste the error messages in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the `gcc` command from the home directory (`~`) when the `hello.c` file is in `~/Documents`.

Either navigate to `Documents` using `cd` before running `gcc` or place `hello.c` in the home directory.

Comment: Now that i am in the proper folder, I still receive the error:   hello.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @Benjamin It seems that there is a problem with the way gcc is configured or something https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898199/fatal-error-stdio-h-not-found

Comment: Do i have to download a compiler? Or should it already be pre-loaded for linux? And thank you for the help so far!

Comment: @BenjaminMacedo Which OS are you using? Ubuntu or an Ubuntu derivative? If so try https://askubuntu.com/questions/653324/remove-gcc-from-ubuntu

Comment: I am using a Linux Mint VM

Comment: Mint is an Ubuntu derivative.

Comment: @Benjamin Reinstalling might fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder at which your file is existing, and then save the program.

> foldername>~$ gcc filename.c