# problems installing Python/C extensions on macOS Mojave : fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found

Tags: python, c, macos

I recently updated to macOS Mojave from High Sierra. I tried to compile a Python module that has C extensions, and got the error:

```
fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
```

I already installed xcode command line tools (which fixes this problem for previous macOS < 10.13; see [Fatal error 'stdio.h' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898199/fatal-error-stdio-h-not-found)). I'm using Python2 from an up-to-date Anaconda distribution.

Has anyone else had/fixed this problem on Mojave?